# ODAC: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, odac

I am trying to connect to Oracle Express 11g. I am using ODAC 12c with Visual Studio 2015. Here's how I am trying to connect:

```
OracleConnection con;
con = new OracleConnection("User Id=SYSTEM;Password=manager;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.1.22)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = XE)))");
con.Open();
```

Application crashes and give `Exception` (not `OracleException`) : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` If I do not set connection string, it gives `OracleException` as expected. What's wrong?

Comment: Please show a complete stack trace.

Answer (score 6):

Please make sure reference are correct and Oracle.DataAccess.dll is of correct version.

Please follow below steps. It worked for me.

1. Locate and copy the oraons.dll file in ‘<>product\12.2.0\client_1’ on your oracle install path
2. Paste the file into the ‘<>product\12.2.0\client_1\bin directory

Try calling the code again.

Comment: That DLL's already in the "...\bin" path under the client, and he's using ODAC; does he even have the client installed?  That DLL is also in the ODAC "\bin" path.

Answer (score 1):

please try this solution :

```
string connString = "User Id=SYSTEM;Password=manager;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.1.22)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = XE)))";

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = connString;
conn.Open();
```

For more informations : 
[Oracle Connection in C# - connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408085/oracle-connection-in-c-sharp-connection-string)

Answer (score 0):

OracleConnection Uses Oracle.DataAccess DLL (Its deprecated, read about ODP.net)

You probably have to install oracle client 11g to provide the neccessery DLL.
A few points:

1. Make sure that tns is configure correctly
2. install the ora client by your build settings (32/64 bit)
3. Make sure you add the DLL reference to your solution.