# Oracle Connection in C# - connection string

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odt, odt.net

I'm currently trying to build an application in C# and connecting it to a live db running in Oracle 11g. 
I have the following connection details

```
Host IP: 10.204.1.3 
Port: 1521
DB Name: PROD
```

---

My source code

```
string connString = "DATA SOURCE=10.204.1.3:1521/PROD;PERSIST SECURITY" +
"INFO=True;USER ID=username; PASSWORD=userpass";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
```

I was able to add a connection in Server Explorer with the Connection String used by VS but is having the error below in conn.Open();

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in 
Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

Sorry if this is a basic question, I'm new in VS, and Oracle and can't find the solution in the other part of the web. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using a TNSNames file at all?

Comment: Also, have you hand coded your connection string or have you gone through a wizard to build the connection string up and tested your connection?

Comment: Add a try catch block around the open() call and resolve the ORA error that shows up in the OracleException

Comment: @CodeWarrior I went through the wizard and was actually able to successfully connect to the db. The connection string I'm using is from the db properties in the server explorer.

Comment: Your string concatenation is going to result in `"PERSIST SECURITYINFO=True"`, which is incorrect and I believe will result in an error, if this isn't just a typo on your post.  A correct connection string depends on what provider you are using and which options you are using, see https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/.

Comment: @MarkL sorry, that was a typo. I've been trying to do the strings in the oracle reference since this morning, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My code is now working. I should've read the Oracle documentation (reference below).

```
string connString = "DATA SOURCE=10.204.3.1:1521/PROD;" +
"PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=username; password=password; Pooling 
=False;";

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = connString;
conn.Open();
```

Reference: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/dotnet/Web_version_Fully_Managed_ODPnet_OBE/odpnetmngdrv.html

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionString Oracle : "User Id=userName;Password=...;Data Source= localhost/mypdb"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).